# How to build with different setting for a test category on TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

I have a situation where my project needs to be tested in x64, but now I'm adding Coded UI tests which need to run in 32 bits.

I have previously used the multi-configuration option to spread work across multiple agents

[image]

The problem is that adding another variable for the test settings file will cause my build to run all categories in both x64 and x86 test settings and I want to be able to choose which categories use which settings, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Seems you want to achieve only build specifically configuration and platform such as `Debug|x86` , `Release|x64`.

You cannot specify **unique** combinations of variables. For now, vNext Build will always build **all permutations** of the variables specified.

You could add a uservoice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services), TFS admin and PM will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the case, my tests use a DLL that only works in x64, but I want to combine them with Coded UI tests, which only run in x86, so I'm trying `Code UI Tests|x86` and `Other Tests|x64` and I'd like them to run in parallel across different agents.